How to define a function that maps 2 elements of a triple to the remaining element in the triple?
Let me explain more in here.
$A$ is a set of many triples of the form $(v,c,t)$, $B$ is a set of pairs $(q,p)$.
To be more precise, $A$ and $B$ are actually outputs of a program in computer science, where $v$ is a string, e.g. "abcd", $c$ and $t$ are the values(numbers) related to this string. $q$ is also a string, e.g. "bcde", and $p$ is the value corresponding to this string.
The union of sets $A$ and $B$ is $S$, so apparently $S$ now contains all the pairs and triples from $A$ and $B$, and $S$ is in reality the sum of results of the program.
I want a function $f$ that takes $(v,c)$ as an identifier for $t$, such that $f(v,c)=t$ and $q$ as an identifier for $p$, such that $f(q)=p$. So something like this:
$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 t & \text{if } x = (v, c) \text{ and } (v, c, t) \in S \\
    p & \text{if } x = q \text{ and } (q,p) \in S \\
\end{cases}$
This may not be mathematically correct, but this is the idea. Can anyone help me with this?

Welcome to Math StackExchange! As it stands, without more context, it's impossible to say whether there is any such function or not. Please edit your question to provide more information, including your own thoughts and efforts.

Hi @CameronBuie, thank you very much for the reminder. This is my first post, so wasn't very sure how to type stuff. Now I have edited the question.

That's much clearer! I have voted to reopen your question. Two key questions remain. Is $B$ a function (a set of pairs that, loosely, passes the "vertical line test"), or not? If not, then it won't be possible. The same question applies to the set $$C:=\Bigl{\bigl((v,c),t\bigr):(v,c,t)\in A\Bigl}.$$ If the answer is "yes" to both, then $B\cup C$ is the only possible solution. It will work if none of the strings in $B$'s domain are equal to a pair in $C$'s domain (and maybe even if there is overlap in domains).

Thank you. @CameronBuie. To answer your questions: strings $q$ in $(q,p) \in B$ do not overlap with anything in set $A$, therefore not in $C$.  I think $B$ is a function, because each $q$ in Set B only has one value $p$. Same applies to set $A$, i.e. when given $(v,c)$, there will only be one corresponding $t$.

In that case, you're in luck! And also, you're welcome. :-)

To cut down on the number of unanswered questions, I'll make our discussion in the comments above into an official answer.
The big kicker is that a function is (or at least can be thought of as) a collection of ordered pairs--with the first entry in each pair indicating an input and the second indicating an output--with the property that each input has a unique output. That is, if $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ are elements of the same function, then $y=z.$
One immediate consequence of this property is that, given two functions $f$ and $g,$ we have that $f\cup g$ (the union of the functions $f$ and $g$) is a function if and only if we have that $f(x)=g(x)$ for every common element $x$ of the domains (collection of inputs) of $f$ and $g$. As a corollary, if the domains of $f$ and $g$ have no elements in common, then $f\cup g$ is automatically a function.
In your particular case, the set $B$ is already a function, and the set $A$ is almost a function. Letting $$C:=\Bigl\{\bigl((v,c),t\bigr)\mid(v,c,t)\in A\Bigr\},$$ we effectively have encoded the same information as we get from $A,$ but in the form of a function (whose inputs just happen to be ordered pairs). Thus, as long as none of the string inputs of $B$ match any of the ordered pair inputs of $C,$ the function you want is exactly $B\cup C.$

If most administrators are like you, who would be willing to shed a ray of light for beginners, the world would be a better place.
